# execfile() Equivalent for Swift

Tags: swift, terminal

I would like to execute a plain text file as Swift. In Python, the following would work:

```
execfile("filePath")
```

Is it possible to accomplish the same thing in Swift?

Note: I am working with Terminal in Mac OS X.

Comment: With *run* do you mean *treat the file as swift and execute that swift code*?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the confusion. I will update the question.

Comment: You want to 'execute a plain text file as Swift' from within another program or from the terminal?

Comment: Yes. In the same way that I showed in python.

Comment: 'Yes' does not answer an 'or' question...

Comment: I misread the question as two separate clauses, **You want to 'execute a plain text file as Swift',** _from within another program or from the terminal?_ to which the answer was yes. To your actual question, Terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NSTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003745) to run the `swift` command:

```
import Foundation
NSTask.launchedTaskWithLaunchPath("/usr/bin/swift", arguments: ["filePath"])
```

Comment: It seems to be running but I am getting a lot of errors. I am trying to do a hello world program: `print(“Hello World”)` (the only contents of the file) but it is not working.

Comment: @Acoop What are the errors?

Comment: @Acoop Did you copy/paste the file contents directly into the comment?  If so, the problem is probably the curly quotes (`“”` instead of `""`).

Comment: The line `print(“Hello World”)` are the only contents of the file that I am trying to execute. It seems to execute, but fails on errors regarding the text of the file. It keeps on printing `\f0\fs24 \cf0 print(\'93Hello World\'94);}` It is possible that it has the wrong encoding?

Comment: What's the output from typing `cat filePath` in the terminal?

Comment: @Acoop Is it something like this: `{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf340
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs24 \cf0 print(\'93Hello, world!\'94)}`

Comment: cat "filePath" does not seem to be working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100410/discussion-between-nobodynada-and-acoop).